# Cross-database references are not implemented in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, where-clause

DB: Postgres

In my entity class I have this code

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true)
    @Where(clause = "balance_as_of = (" +
            "select max(account_balance.balance_as_of) " +
            "from \"schema-name\".account_balance " +
            "where account_balance.id = id)")
    private List<AccountBalance> balances;
```

During runtime, this code is converted to actual SQL query which is

```
select balances0_.account_id as account_6_1_0_, balances0_.id as id1_1_0_, balances0_.id as id1_1_1_, balances0_.account_id as account_6_1_1_, balances0_.available_balance as availabl2_1_1_, balances0_.balance_as_of as balance_3_1_1_, balances0_.incoming_balance as incoming4_1_1_, balances0_.outgoing_balance as outgoing5_1_1_ from "schema-name".account_balance balances0_ where ( balances0_.balance_as_of = (select max(account_balance.balance_as_of) from **balances0_."schema-name".account_balance** where account_balance.id = balances0_.id)) and balances0_.account_id=?
```

Then it throws the error

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "balances0_.schema-name.account_balance"`

My expectation was the inner SQL should generate correctly based on the **@Where** annotation clause value.  Unfortunately, during runtime, it added an additional  **balances0_** in front of the schema name which should not be there. This **balances0_** is the table alias of the outer SQL.

If I remove the "schema-name", it says table does not exist as I think it was referring to the public schema.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view that hides the database reference and use that in your where clause.